# How do I provide an UI to setup a Team Foundation Server 2015 plugin?

Tags: tfs, build, customization, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've developed a Team Foundation Server 2015 plugin implementing `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ISubscriber` interface from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server` assembly.

I would like to provide some configuration to the plugin, but I want it in the Team Foundation Server UI.

Actually, I've developed some plugin to trigger a build under some special condition, and it would be wonderful if I could configure some parameters in the *Triggers* tab on new scriptable build definitions (see the following picture)

[image: TFS 2015 new build definition system settings]

Is it possible to add some new UI section to *Triggers* or, at least, an entire new tab there?

*My alternative would be instructing the user to add some variables to **Variables** tab...*